# Mathematica SQL zerodatetimes

Tags: mysql, wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to query SQL data with MATHEMATICA - however, the MySQL database contains zerodates and that leads to the following error message:

e.g. (1)
**SQLSelect[conn, "orders", {"time_created"}, MaxRows -> 5]**
--> *JDBC::error: "!(\"Cannot convert value '0000-00-00 00:00:00' from column 1 to TIMESTAMP.\")"*

e.g. (2)
**SQLExecute[conn, "SELECT * FROM `orders`", MaxRows -> 5]**
--> *JDBC::error: "!(\"Cannot convert value '0000-00-00 00:00:00' from column 6 to TIMESTAMP.\")"*

I found out that this is a typical issue with a JDBC connection and that this can be solved by allowing ***zerodatetimes*** as true with examples from other systems. What I didn't find out is: ***How to apply this specifically in Mathematica?*** Can you advise me?

It would help me a lot - so thank you very much for any help!